# To compute double integral by using transformation

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Given $u = \dfrac{x^2+y^2}{x}, v = \dfrac{x^2+y^2}{y}$ ,

evaluate $\displaystyle\iint xy\,dx\,dy $

over the region is common to

$x^2+y^2=x , x^2+y^2=y.$

I have computed the Jacobian. But how do I write $xy$ in terms of $u$ and $v$ and how do I find the limits? Thanks!

J= $$\frac{xy}{uv}$$

Comment: What did you calculate as the Jacobian? It matters in terms of finding $xy$ in terms of $u$ and $v$. Also, your bounds don't make sense. $x^2+y^2=x$ and $x^2+y^2=y$ are both cylinders, in the 2D plane they're overlapping circles. Are the bounds the intersection of the two circles?

Comment: Yes region common to both circles\

Comment: The jacobian should be entirely in terms of $u$ and $v$... how did you find $J$?

Comment: yes it was in terms of u and v only. I just replaced expression by x and y , thinking it would cancel with given integrand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jacobian determinant is correct.

The transformation can be easily inverted:

$u/v=y/x$

$u=\dfrac{(x^2+y^2)/x^2}{x/x^2}=\dfrac{1+y^2/x^2}{1/x}$

$x=\dfrac{u}{1+u^2/v^2}=\dfrac{uv^2}{u^2+v^2}$

and

$y=\dfrac{u^2v}{u^2+v^2}$

The region is the intersection of the sets $\{0<u<1\}$ and $\{0<v<1\}$

The integral follows:

$$I=\int_0^1\int_0^1xy|J|\mathbb du\mathbb dv=\int_0^1\int_0^1\dfrac{x^2y^2}{uv}\mathbb du\mathbb dv$$

$$I=\int_0^1\int_0^1\dfrac{u^5v^5}{(u^2+v^2)^4}\mathbb du\mathbb dv$$

Comment: your simplification part  is incorrect and how did you get the limits of u and v. exponent should be 4 in denomiantor

Comment: Corrected. It is obvious that the boundary of the region of integration is contained in the curves $u=1$ and $v=1$. From here, the region of integration contains part of all curves with $0<u<1$ and $0<v<1$ and no other curve (values for $u=constant$ determine circles passing by the origin and center in the axis; analogously for $v$). Each point of the region is uniquely determined by pairs of values for $u,v$ as they define curves.

Comment: Sorry it is not obvious to me. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: If you set $u=1$ you get exactly $x^2+y^2=x$ and with $v=1$, $x^2+y^2=y$. Values $u<1$ draw circles into $x^2+y^2=x$

Comment: aand how to solve last uv double integral

Comment: I didn't try to solve it. It's not clear the benefit in calculations of this transformation, so I supposed it is an exercise to show how to simplify the integration limits (basically by "transforming the equations for the limiting curves into formulas for a change of variables")